# iPhone cross-domain ajax request fails

Tags: iphone, jquery

Hi I am creating an application where I used ajax request to populate the List of Items.
    It works in PC-Browser but not works in iPhone safari.
    What could be the issue in safari? Please Help.

```
createXMLHTTPHandle:function(url,onSuccess,onError){
                    var xhttp;
                    try {
                        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        } else {
                            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        xhttp.open("GET", url, false);
                        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",        
                                        "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
                        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            if(xhttp.readyState == 4) {
                                if(xhttp.status == 200)//clear db and parse 
                                                   and store new data
                                {
                                    onSuccess(xhttp.responseText);
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        xhttp.send();
                    }
                    catch(err) {//
        if(err=="Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest  Exception 101")
        alert("Please check your network    connection!");
                        onError(err);
                    }
                 }
```

Comment: No code, no examples, no nothing???